# How can I turn off Retweets from persons I am following?

Tags: twitter

I like (most of) the people I follow. But some of them just Retweet a bunch of noise. Is there an option in Twitter to turn off these Retweets ? I already can I see the top Retweets in the sidebar so I definitely would like to remove it from my home timeline.

There used to be this option

[image]

I am not seeing it again, instead I see the set up mobile texts option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a link to the **[Twitter Support page on retweets](https://support.twitter.com/entries/77606-what-is-retweet-rt)**:

> Select **Turn off Retweets** from the person icon drop-down menu on a user's profile to stop seeing Tweets they've retweeted.

There are more details of how you can fine tune settings on that Twitter support page, along with an illustration showing how to do it. The page is really long. The section about turning off retweets is about 2/3 of the way down.

Comment: your link showed "Forbidden" text on my browser, is it just me or anyone else got this?

Comment: Twitter seem to have changed support URLs, I updated the answer