# How do I get my Twitter followers not to appear on my timeline?

Tags: twitter

I have just joined Twitter and when I follow people, I get all their tweets in my timeline. I have been to other people's pages and I can see only what they have tweeted in their timeline but they are following people.

Why aren't their follower's tweets in their timeline? (Some have got thousands of followers.) I can't keep up!

So, how are they doing it?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Welcome to the WebApps Stack Exchange. We love to see your questions here, but if you could limit each post to one question that will make answering your question(s) a lot easier and more accurate.

Comment: more often than not, you end up missing lots of tweets. For that reason I have a private list consisting of people who I want to read *all* of their tweets.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the Twitter experience.

Your [home timeline](https://support.twitter.com/articles/164083), the page you see when you log in, will contain tweets from your own account along with all of those you are following and other tweets that have been retweeted (if you haven't [turned that off](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/how-can-i-turn-off-retweets-from-persons-i-am-following)).

This is found here:

> https://twitter.com/

When you view a profile's timeline you only see tweets from them and their retweets. You'll know you're on a profile timeline when the URL is like:

> `https://twitter.com/{username}`

How they keep up depends on how they use it and various apps they might use with Twitter.

Some people follow thousands but don't really check their timeline and only look [at any mentions toward them](https://twitter.com/mentions). Others might [create a list or two](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists) with a few tweeters and only check that, cutting down on the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit of a confusion to me but I think you want to know how it is that on your timeline, you're seeing all your followings tweets. Correct?

Well, if you entered `www.twitter.com/{your username}` into the web browser's address bar, you should see all your tweets alone.

When you go to the homepage of Twitter, after logging in, you will see tweets from the people that you're following.

So you said, *“I follow people, I get all their tweets in my timeline.”*—If you checked the URL of that page, it would probably be the homepage of Twitter. Which, after logging in, shows your timeline (and NOT your profile).

And, *“I have been to other people's pages and I can see only what they have tweeted in their timeline but they are following people.”*—Check the URL, you should probably see `www.twitter.com/{their username}`. It's their profile that you're viewing.

They can follow any amount of people, but when you go to their profile page, which is `www.twitter.com/{their username}`, you'd only see their tweets and retweets (retweets are tweets from other people tweeted by this person).

It's how Twitter works.